# PHP cannot write in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a workflow in docker.
It's simple: just PHP and MySQL to little tests.

My **docker-compose.yml**:

```
web:
  build: .docker
  links:
    - mysql:mysql
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  volumes:
    - ./public_html:/var/www/html
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
  volumes:
    - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  links:
    - mysql:mysql
  environment:
    - PMA_HOST=mysql
  volumes:
    - /sessions
```

And my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

It's all ok: I can up containers but PHP itself cannot write in directories (like `fwrite()` or similar).

I researched a lot and tried a lot of tutorials, but nothing...

Comment: can you show me your php Dockerfile? i think its caused by a permission issue.

Comment: I guess you are write @Gabbax0r but I'm new in Linux...
My Dockerfile is already in question and points to [php5.6-apache](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/1c56325a69718a3e3cf76179e75d070b7e23da62/5.6/Dockerfile) in HUB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apache runs PHP with the user `www-data`, this user needs to have write access on your host directory `./public_html`

To fix that, go to your docker-compose directory and execute the following command to change the owner of your `public_html`directory and all files inside.

```sh
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data public_html
```

After that you need to allow users in the group "www-data" to edit files

```sh
# To change all the directories to 775 
# (write for user & group www-data, read for others):
find public_html -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

# To change all the files to 664
# (write for user & group www-data, read for others):
find public_html -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

---

In order for your current user to edit these files you need to add it to the `www-data` group :

```sh
sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER
```

Comment: It's `chown -R`

Comment: I just delete everything and tried to create a new repository with your solution and worked. Thank you @ChVuagniaux