# Php is unable to write file in docker

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, symfony-3.4

I am runing a Symfony 3.4 application with docker, i need to upload a file and save it to /web/files. When i'm trying to do so i get an error:

```
Unable to create the "/home/docker/web/files/" directory
```

Note that i mounted the directory as Read-Write in cocker compose:

```
version: '2'
services:  

  front:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    links:
      - "engine:engine"
      - "db:db"
    volumes:
      - ".:/home/docker:ro"
      - "./docker/front/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro"

  engine:
    build: ./docker/engine/
    volumes:
      - ".:/home/docker:rw"
      - "./docker/engine/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini:ro"
    links:
      - "db:db"
    working_dir: "/home/docker"

  db:
    image: camptocamp/postgres:9.6
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_DB=pfe"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=admin"
      - "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
```

I even created the directory files in /web, but its not working!

Answer (score 0):

I create a separate container for my files, and just base it on an apache image. Then I use the `volumes_from` key to pass it into my php. Give something like this a try:

```
services:
    apache:
        build: ./build/httpd
        links:
            - php
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes_from:
            - app

    php:
        build: ./build/php
        ports:
            - 9000
            - 9001
        volumes_from:
            - app
        links:
            - mariadb
            - mail

    app:
        image: httpd:latest
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
        command: "echo true"
```

Comment: I dont see the purpuse of runing another Apache container, but i found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842112/php-cannot-write-in-docker-container

Comment: it's just a container that syncs your files and apparently is faster, it could have been any old image tbh. Notice I haven't set any permissions at all, and I never get any permission errors. Regarding that answer you found, did you run that command INSIDE your docker, or outside on the host os?